# How can I simplify this compose type?

Tags: typescript

I have a `compose` function that composes React HOCs and copies statics along down through the fns.

I have it working, but the types are an absolute mess and I'm wondering if anyone better with TS than I am might have some clever ideas here:

```
// from a utility lib
type SetDifference<A, B> = A extends B ? never : A;
type Diff<T extends object, U extends object> = Pick<
  T,
  SetDifference<keyof T, keyof U>
>;

// the fn signature
export function compose<A, B extends object, C extends object, D extends object, E extends object>(
  f1: (_: A) => B,
  f2: (_: B) => C,
  f3: (_: C) => D,
  f4: (_: D) => E,
): <T extends object>(
  _: T,
) => T &
  Diff<E, T> & Diff<Diff<D, E>, T> & Diff<Diff<Diff<C, D>, E>, T> & Diff<Diff<Diff<Diff<B, C>, D>, E>, T>
```

The type is basically what you'd get from: `{...B, ...C, ...D, ...E, ...T}`

Any ideas?

[ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20from%20a%20utility%20lib%0D%0Atype%20SetDifference%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%3D%20A%20extends%20B%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20A%3B%0D%0Atype%20Diff%3CT%20extends%20object%2C%20U%20extends%20object%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20SetDifference%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20U%3E%0D%0A%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20builtinProps%20%3D%20new%20Set%28%5B'arguments'%2C%20'caller'%2C%20'length'%2C%20'name'%2C%20'prototype'%5D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20copyStatics%3CA%20extends%20object%2C%20B%20extends%20object%3E%28fromObj%3A%20A%2C%20toObj%3A%20B%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames%28fromObj%29.forEach%28prop%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28builtinProps.has%28prop%29%29%20return%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty%28toObj%2C%20prop%2C%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor%28fromObj%2C%20prop%29!%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20toObj%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20the%20fn%20signature%0D%0Aexport%20function%20compose%3CA%2C%20B%20extends%20object%2C%20C%20extends%20object%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20f1%3A%20%28_%3A%20A%29%20%3D%3E%20B%2C%0D%0A%20%20f2%3A%20%28_%3A%20B%29%20%3D%3E%20C%2C%0D%0A%29%3A%20%3CT%20extends%20object%3E%28_%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20T%20%26%20Diff%3CC%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20Diff%3CDiff%3CB%2C%20C%3E%2C%20T%3E%3B%0D%0Aexport%20function%20compose%3CA%2C%20B%20extends%20object%2C%20C%20extends%20object%2C%20D%20extends%20object%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20f1%3A%20%28_%3A%20A%29%20%3D%3E%20B%2C%0D%0A%20%20f2%3A%20%28_%3A%20B%29%20%3D%3E%20C%2C%0D%0A%20%20f3%3A%20%28_%3A%20C%29%20%3D%3E%20D%2C%0D%0A%29%3A%20%3CT%20extends%20object%3E%28_%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20T%20%26%20Diff%3CD%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20Diff%3CDiff%3CC%2C%20D%3E%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20Diff%3CDiff%3CDiff%3CB%2C%20C%3E%2C%20D%3E%2C%20T%3E%3B%0D%0Aexport%20function%20compose%3CA%2C%20B%20extends%20object%2C%20C%20extends%20object%2C%20D%20extends%20object%2C%20E%20extends%20object%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20f1%3A%20%28_%3A%20A%29%20%3D%3E%20B%2C%0D%0A%20%20f2%3A%20%28_%3A%20B%29%20%3D%3E%20C%2C%0D%0A%20%20f3%3A%20%28_%3A%20C%29%20%3D%3E%20D%2C%0D%0A%20%20f4%3A%20%28_%3A%20D%29%20%3D%3E%20E%2C%0D%0A%29%3A%20%3CT%20extends%20object%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20_%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%29%20%3D%3E%20T%20%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Diff%3CE%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20Diff%3CDiff%3CD%2C%20E%3E%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20Diff%3CDiff%3CDiff%3CC%2C%20D%3E%2C%20E%3E%2C%20T%3E%20%26%20Diff%3CDiff%3CDiff%3CDiff%3CB%2C%20C%3E%2C%20D%3E%2C%20E%3E%2C%20T%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20compose%28...fns%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20x%20%3D%3E%20fns.reduceRight%28%28value%2C%20fn%29%20%3D%3E%20copyStatics%28value%2C%20fn%28value%29%29%2C%20x%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20compose%28%0D%0A%20%20x%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20foo%3A%20123%20%7D%29%2C%0D%0A%20%20x%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20bar%3A%20456%2C%20foo%3A%20'123'%20%7D%29%2C%0D%0A%20%20x%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20bar%3A%20456%2C%20foo%3A%20undefined%20%7D%29%2C%0D%0A%29%28%7B%20baz%3A%20789%2C%20foob%3A%20'asd'%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo.foo%3B%0D%0Afoo.bar%3B%0D%0Afoo.baz%3B)

Comment: You want a [spread type operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) which doesn't exist as of now.  Workarounds range from [just using an intersection](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28323) and calling it a day to complicated conditionals like you're using here.  I don't know that there's a *great* answer.  There might be something which operates on tuples that scales better than yours, but it'll still be a workaround.

Comment: edit: tuple workaround would need to be circular in a way that isn't supported so it's likely to be worse than just hardcoding a type like `Spread<B,Spread<C,Spread<D,Spread<E,T>>>>` for a suitable definition of `Spread<L, R>`

Comment: @jcalz -- Thanks for all the context, it's really helpful.  That's a very, very thorough GH issue, good read.